Checking the formula for solving the Poisson equation with an integral over all of space
EDIT: According to 2.2.3 Rigorous derivation, if we find the integral $u(x,y) = \int \int G(x,y,m,n)f(m,n) dm dn$ then we obtain a function that satisfies the Poisson equation $\nabla^2u(x,y)=f(x,y)$. Let's get for example $f=1$. Green function for 2D Laplacian is $G(x,y|m,n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{\xi}|)$. Let's get some functions for example and here's what happened:
r = {x, y};
\[Xi] = {m, n};
d = Sqrt[(r - \[Xi]) . (r - \[Xi])];
g = 1/(2 Pi) Log[d];
f = 1;
resultfromintegration = Integrate[g f, m, n] // Simplify
resultfromode = 
 DSolve[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f}, {u[x, y]}, {x, y}] // 
  Simplify

Question: Why are the results not the same?
Theory: Poisson's equation is frequently written as $\nabla^{2}\phi=f$
In three-dimensional Cartesian coordinates, it takes the form $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z^2})\phi(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)$
I want to check how the Poisson solution works using the following formula (taken from here):
$\phi(\boldsymbol{r}) =\iiint \frac{f(\boldsymbol{r}')}{4 \pi|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}'|} \,d^3\boldsymbol{r}'$
As I understand it, this integral can be rewritten in the following form:
$\phi(x,y,z) =\iiint \frac{f(x',y',z')}{4 \pi \sqrt {(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}} \,dx'\,dy'\,dz'$
Well, let's take the function $\phi(x,y,z)=x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2$. Applying the Laplace operator, we obtain $\nabla^{2}\phi(x,y,z)=2yz+2xz+2xy$.
Now suppose our Poisson equation looks like this $\nabla^{2}\phi(x,y,z)=2yz+2xz+2xy$.
And now I want to apply the formula for solving the Poisson equation with a triple integral over all of space and compare the resulting function with the original one. Here's what happened:
\[Phi][x, y, z] = x^2 y z + x y^2 z + x y z^2
f[x, y, z] = Laplacian[\[Phi][x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
r = {x, y, z}
r' = {x', y', z'}
green[x, y, z] = 1/(4 Pi Sqrt[(r - r') . (r - r')])
result = 
 Integrate[
   Integrate[
    Integrate[
     green[x, y, z] ReplaceAll[
       f[x, y, z], {x -> x', y -> y', z -> z'}], x'], y'], z'] // 
  Simplify

But the problem is that the integral is not calculated. What is the reason, I wrote it down incorrectly? Apparently the phrase over all of space is of great importance for the form of writing the integral and it needs to be formed differently?

Just two small comments: (1) Please look at the InputForm[x']. You will see that this represents Derivative[1][x]. Hence, you should generally not be using ' to denoted the "primed" variables. Instead, use for example xp, yp, zp. (2) Instead of doing Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[...]]], you can just do one Integrate[..., xp, yp, zp]. However, none of these two comments make any difference regarding getting the result :)

@Domen I used your recommendations. Look at the wording of the question.

This is rather a math than Mathematica question. The integral formula can be applied only if $\phi(x,y,z)\to 0$ as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to \infty$ (for example, see p.36 here ). But
Limit[x^2  y  z + x  y^2  z +  x  y  z^2, 
{x, y, z} -> {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, Direction -> "FromBelow"]


Infinity

Addition. Concerning your edit, i.e.
r = {x, y};\[Xi] = {m, n};d = Sqrt[(r - \[Xi]) . (r - \[Xi])];
g = 1/(2 Pi) Log[d];f = 1;
resultfromintegration = Integrate[g f, m, n] // Simplify
resultfromode = DSolve[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f}, {u[x, y]}, {x, y}] // Simplify

,  I repeat that " using the formula assumes that the improper integral converges, but this is not the case in the case under consideration". Your resultfromintegration is nothing but antiderivative of antiderivative. It should be resultfromintegration =   Integrate[g  f, {m, -Infinity, Infinity}, {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] //Simplify instead of. As far as I understand it, DSolve does not use any Green function to this end.

It is sad. It turns out that the triple integral formula does not always work?

Yes, of course. There is no formula for all seasons.

In other words, using the formula assumes that the improper integral converges, but this is not the case in the case under consideration.

see my edit, please

@ayr: I repeat that " using the formula assumes that the improper integral converges, but this is not the case in the case under consideration". Your resultfromintegration is nothing but  antiderivative of antiderivative. It should be resultfromintegration =   Integrate[g  f, {m, -Infinity, Infinity}, {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] //    Simplify instead of.

As far as I understand it, DSolve does not use any Green function to this end.
